# spark standalone cluster vs Eclipse classnonfoundexeption

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I use Eclipse IDE, added to my project all jars from spark as "add external jars", use spark-cassandra connector. Use standalone cluster.
my code example code is :

```
import com.datastax.spark.driver._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object connect extends App {
val conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("spark://192.168.0.1:7077").setAppName("test").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.0.2")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("ks", "tbl")
```

if i try to use `println(rdd.count)` everything works, but if i use `val filterRdd = rdd.filter(x => x.getString(1).contains("teststr")) println (filterRdd.count)` i get ClassNonFoundException.

it not only for cassandra, every action with rdd results in error. locally for local master it works perfectly.

How can i get it work, my laptop can not connect to internet, so i cant use maven, so i download all jars and exported it locally. And on each spark slave i puted spark-cassandra-connector.jar

Comment: Have you added the scala folder to class path? If not:
Right click on project -> properties -> java build path -> Add folder -> check scala folder -> save/apply –

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Just export my project as jar in Eclipse in local folder and in my code add `sc.addJars("localPathToJar")` and it works